# Есть ли в js аналог статических переменных в функциях, как в php?

Tags: javascript

Есть ли аналог такого кода в js?

```
function doStuff() {
  static $cache = null;
  echo $cache;
  if ($cache === null) {
     $cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
  }

  // code using $cache
}
doStuff() //prints null
doStuff() //prints '%heavy database stuff or something%'
```

Для примера
в первый раз `doStuff()` выводит null, а во второй `'%heavy database stuff or something%'`

Какие есть варианты?

Как то можно было схитрить с анонимными функциями, но забыл

Answer (score 6):

Мне кажется Вы ищете замыкание:

```js
var doStuff = (function (){
  var cache = null;
  return function() {
    console.log(cache)
    if (cache === null)
      cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
  }
})();

doStuff();
doStuff();
```

Comment: Приватная получается. Или в вопросе тоже приватная?

Comment: В вопросе `Чтобы зона видимости была только для этой функции`

Comment: Ну тогда твой вариант больше подходит :) А я невнимательно читаю :(

Comment: Ну или просто не мешалась...)

Answer (score 1):

Поле самой функции:

```js
function doStuff() {
  console.log(doStuff.cache);

  if (doStuff.cache === null) {
     doStuff.cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
  }
}

doStuff.cache = null;

doStuff() //prints null
doStuff() //prints '%heavy database stuff or something%'
```

Кстати, я бы обошёлся `undefined`ом:

```js
function doStuff() {
  console.log(doStuff.cache);

  if (doStuff.cache == null) {
     doStuff.cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
  }
}

doStuff() //prints undefined
doStuff() //prints '%heavy database stuff or something%'
```

Comment: А так не сделаешь в typescript. Надо тогда вместо doStuff.cache писать doStuff['cache']

Comment: Но такой вариант легче читать.

Comment: @AlexanderMyravjev, `doStuff.cache = null as string | null;` - нет ошибки: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmW14.png

Answer (score 0):

Можно так еще

```
{
    let cache = null ;
    function doStuff(){
        console.log(cache)
        if (cache === null){
           cache = '%heavy database stuff or something%';
        }
    }
}

doStuff() ; //prints null
doStuff() ; //prints '%heavy database stuff or something%'
```

Comment: Это неправильно. Точнее, это работает только до добавления `"use strict"`.